# Can I force the use of 'this' keyword in c# .NET?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, syntax, conventions

Is there a way to force the use of the `this` keyword in Visual Studio when referencing current instance members?

**Example with a bug in the constructor:**

```
class MyClass
{
    public object Foo { get; set; }
    public MyClass(object foo)
    {
        Foo = Foo; // this should of course be lowercase but it's easy to miss
    }
}
```

This code will probably generate the infamous `'object reference not set to an instance of an object'` exception somewhere later on.

**How to make it work but still It's easy to miss:**

```
class MyClass
{
    public object Foo { get; set; }
    public MyClass(object foo)
    {
        Foo = foo; // Valid syntax but unclear.
    }
}
```

This is valid syntax but it's easy to miss.

**The syntax I'd like visual studio enforce:**

```
class MyClass
{
    public object Foo { get; set; }
    public MyClass(object foo)
    {
        this.Foo = foo; // this is "safe". 
    }
}
```

If this convention is enforced i would have to type `this.Foo = this.Foo` to create the same type of bug as in the first example.

I always use the `this` keyword anyway since it makes my life easier while switching between c# and other languages so there wouldn't be any disadvantages at all.

Comment: Visual studio does warn you when you do the first mistake if you use fxcop

Comment: As you said I don't think that would make any difference to the problem you're having, I'd suggest changing parameter's name instead to something like `bar`, this way you wouldn't have any problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can fix this simply by enabling "Treat warnings as errors":

> Warning   2   Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?

(CS1717 if you want to enable it just for this one)

The compiler already tells you about this; you should be reviewing the warnings (and aim for zero warnings).

Re the middle one being unclear:

```
Foo = foo;
```

I disagree - that is perfectly clear to me (unless you come from a VB background and have developed case-blindness).

Comment: What he meant is that you can never write `Foo` if you mean `this.Foo`, which you mean in the second example. So his way would catch that one

Comment: Indeed, but you wrote that it would still be an error which is not true

Comment: Yeah, feels like it's more relevant now

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently refactoring a large project so I have 100+ "xxx is obsolete"-warnings so I think I just missed it. I agree totally, there should be zero warnings when shipping.

Comment: @Jonas - you can enable the "warning as error" oh a error-by-error basis if it helps

Comment: Sorry @MarcGravell, but this answer is incorrect. The warning also signals in case of variables; not in case properties are used.

Comment: @Steven yup; and in that case it is *still* almost certainly a bug, hence no reason to ignore the warning that the compiler already generates

Comment: I'm sorry, my previous comment was misleading. in case you do this WITH properties, there will be NO warning.

Comment: Still doesn't tell you if we can enforce use of this.* to make context clearer.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't change the behaviour of the language like this. If you use ReSharper I *believe* you can tell it to flag up this sort of thing - it may not come up in the error list, but in the margin and in an "indicator light" for the overall file health.

I personally don't *tend* to lose too much sleep over this sort of thing, as it's *usually* obvious as soon as you test - I can only recall one scenario where it's really bitten me, which was when I ended up with a stack overflow (not exactly the same situation, but again a casing issue) within a type initializer, running on Windows Phone 7 - a mixture of difficult debug environments, basically.

Comment: I agree, I came up with the idea while unit testing so it isn't a big deal really. I just thought it would be a "Nice to have"-feature.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [StyleCop](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) to generate a warning if you do not prefix with this. You can get StyleCop to run as part of the build process by following these [these instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sourceanalysis/archive/2008/05/24/source-analysis-msbuild-integration.aspx)

StyleCop comes with a bunch of default rules, many of them terrible, but you can edit your rules file to make the most sense for your developers. You can also share the StyleCop file so changes are immediately replicated to all your developers.

Its a fairly nice solution, free, provided by Microsoft and if you come up with a suitable rule set then your developers will create much "neater" code. You can also create custom rules along the lines of "Methods shouldn't be too long" where you define the length. Plenty of things to play with.

Also I guess you could set warnings as errors, but if you do make sure your StyleCop settings are exactly as you want them.

Comment: What a great tool! I've used the FxCop but this a nice complement.

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom warnings and errors using FXCop\Visual Studio Code Analysis

Comment: there is an existing compiler warning; no custom rule is required

Comment: I meant, you can create a custom warning that will notify on accessing local properties without "this"

Comment: That's the way to go if you want to be pedantic about it. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use `StyleCopAnalyzers`, rule [SA1101](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1101.md):

> **Cause:**
>
> A call to an instance member of the local class or a base class is not prefixed with 'this.', within a C# code file.

Then you can right click the rule in solution explorer and set it to error, now it will not compile if "this" is not used.